# How to change the text color of Spinner drop down items?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I would like to change the text color of the Spinner drop down items to black.

I have a custom Spinner that lists different languages. It has an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. The Spinner is shown on a blue background with white text and it looks fine.

The problem is when it is clicked, the drop down shows up but the text is barely visible because of the light gray color of the drop down and the white color of the text.

This is the code for the Spinner in the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/languageSpinner"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:prompt="@string/selectLanguageSpinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

This is the `spinner_row_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/language"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="20dp"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here the text color is set to white, because I need it to be white when nothing is selected.

This is the code in `styles.xml`:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myAppPrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myAppPrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAppAccentColor</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/TestSpinnerStyle</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="mySpinnerItemStyle">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">3dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ^^ Here I need to set the color to white, because I also have default
             spinner on the activity that needs to have a default white color. 
             But when the default spinner is clicked, the color of the 
             drop down items is black. How can I do that with my custom spinner? -->

    <style name="TestSpinnerStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:height">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@color/gray</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/default_gray</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ^^ The text color property here is not reflected.. -->
```

Does anybody have any suggestions how to do that?

**EDIT:** After the help from the comments and the answers, I managed to do it. I thought that it could be done in XML...Anyways in the java code behind, this is what I did:

When the custom adapter is defined, we need to override the `getDropDownView` method, which is fired when the spinner is clicked and the drop down shows up. The `getView` method should also be overridden, so we can handle the default color when the `Spinner` is not clicked. In other words, here is the code:

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects, TypedArray image){
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row_layout, parent, false);

            TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.language);
            label.setText(languages_list[position]);

            label.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));

            ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageDrawable(icons_list.getDrawable(position));

            return row;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row_layout, parent, false);

            TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.language);
            textView.setText(languages_list[position]);
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

            ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageDrawable(icons_list.getDrawable(position));

            return row;
        }
    }
```

Notice that the color of the `TextView` in `getDropDownView` is set to black, while in `getView` it is set to white.

Comment: Are you using own implementation of adapter for showing Spinner items?

Comment: @flyingAssistant I've done it as in this tutorial: http://www.edureka.co/blog/custom-spinner-in-android/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done that thing like that, but in `BaseAdapter`

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);
            }

            TextView txtTestText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSpinnerRowText);
            txtTestText.setText(list.get(position).getText());
            if (getSelectedPosition() == position) {
                txtTestText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
            } else {
                txtTestText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_light));
            }
            return view;
        }
```

Comment: What is `getSelectedPosition()` ?

Comment: It's an index of selected `Spinner` row item, defined in `BaseAdapter` as field. I change this index whenever a `Spinner` dropdown item is selected (`OnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected`) or unselected (`OnItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected`).

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do it. I'll edit my question with the full solution. I was able to change the color in the `getDropDownView` and in `getView`, so it looks fine now.

Answer (score 0):

try this I hope is't work.

```
((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnergender)).setAdapter(adapter);
        ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnergender)).setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e("Value",""+position);
                ((TextView) ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnergender)).getSelectedView()).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cyan));
                if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.Gender))) {
                    ((TextView) ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnergender)).getSelectedView()).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Text));
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create custom adapter (that extends BaseAdapter) for spinner and on getDropDownView inflate custom spinner_item_dropdown.xml, which is set to your wishes.